# Why does libwebp-imageio make Tomcat crash?

Tags: tomcat, crash, webp

I use libwebp-imageio in my web project, but it makes my Tomcat crash.
here's the log info:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x00007f5a92ca41ee, pid=16484, tid=0x00007f5a98b2c700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebp-imageio.so+0x321ee]  VP8EncLoop+0xbe
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

----thread info ----

```
Stack: [0x00007f5a98a2c000,0x00007f5a98b2d000],  sp=0x00007f5a98b29f90,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libwebp-imageio.so+0x321ee]  VP8EncLoop+0xbe

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 15333  com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebP.encodeRGB(J[BIII)[B (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b2facd8df [0x00007f5b2facd880+0x5f]
J 24588 C2 com.luciad.imageio.webp.WebPWriter.write(Ljavax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadata;Ljavax/imageio/IIOImage;Ljavax/imageio/ImageWriteParam;)V (49 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b304dae20 [0x00007f5b304da580+0x8a0]
J 20937 C2 javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)Z (86 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b2ef43074 [0x00007f5b2ef42980+0x6f4]
J 22663 C2 com.onemt.news.crawler.recycle.business.entity.NewsImage.getLargersTwo(Lcom/onemt/news/crawler/recycle/business/entity/NewsImage;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/onemt/news/crawler/recycle/business/entity/NewsImage; (395 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b30bc5388 [0x00007f5b30bc2e40+0x2548]
J 24304 C2 com.onemt.news.crawler.recycle.common.CommonDownloadImageUtils.downloadImage(Lcom/onemt/news/crawler/recycle/common/CommonImage;Lcom/onemt/news/crawler/recycle/business/entity/PageImage;Ljava/lang/Long;Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V (793 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b3113e0dc [0x00007f5b3113ae00+0x32dc]
J 24069 C2 com.onemt.news.crawler.feeler.text.pipeline.NewsPipeline.downloadImages(Lcom/onemt/news/crawler/recycle/business/entity/PageArticle;Ljava/lang/Long;)Ljava/util/List; (114 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b2fdb1ee0 [0x00007f5b2fdb1d60+0x180]
J 21829 C2 com.onemt.news.crawler.feeler.text.pipeline.NewsPipeline.process(Lus/codecraft/webmagic/ResultItems;Lus/codecraft/webmagic/Task;)V (905 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b3097361c [0x00007f5b3096f680+0x3f9c]
J 24848 C2 us.codecraft.webmagic.thread.CountableThreadPool$1.run()V (134 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b305325fc [0x00007f5b30531ba0+0xa5c]
J 23258% C2 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V (225 bytes) @ 0x00007f5b302078d8 [0x00007f5b30207660+0x278]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

uname:Linux 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 65535, NOFILE 65535, AS infinity
load average:0.57 0.30 0.33

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried to repair the problem? Please show some effort.

Comment: Usually the JRE will provide a Java stack trace along with as much of the native stack trace as possible. Can you post more of the error log?

Comment: I Increased jvm memory,bug it appeared 3 days later.The jvm gc graph  is normal.It isn't  abnormal immediately in my local.And the cause of the tomcat crash is the same